# Build an SQL query dynamically based on columns' datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

In my app, i have a feature where the user can enter multiple search fields and these will be used to query the db, for example, the user enters:

> smith 123456 london 12/01/2020

These fields will be passed to a stored procedure as a table-valued parameter (consisting of one column as varchar). The sp uses a view as its datasource. For example for the above custom search, there will be a view with the following columns:

```
number, int
firstname, varchar
lastname, varchar
dob, datetime
address, varchar
```

The sp needs to build the sql query dynamically and this query should look like

```
select * from customersview
where 'smith' in (firstname, lastname, address)
and 123456 in (number)
and 'london' in (firstname, lastname, address)
and '12/01/2029' in (dob)
```

So basically, what the sp does is:

1. Take the search filters and determine what datatype they are
2. Map the filters' datatype with columns' datatype, so that, for example, an `int` filter is mapped to all `int` columns, etc.

So I started off with the following:

```
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS v
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c on c.TABLE_SCHEMA = v.TABLE_SCHEMA
and c.TABLE_NAME = v.TABLE_NAME
where c.TABLE_NAME = 'customersview'
```

which will give me the view's columns and their datatype.

But how can I match the data types (because the filters come in a TVP) so that I can build the various conditions?

Alternatively, I can change the TableType so that it has 3 unique columns (int, varchar, datetime) and the app determines the data type and adds the value in the correct column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to build the query using a while loop and checking the datatype as following.

I have added comments in the query itself for easy understanding.

**TODO**:

1- You need to add other datatypes the below query.

2- You need to parameterized the query and use `sp_executesql` instead of execute to avoid any **sql injection attack**.

```
--Table to Store search inputs, which will be your table type parameter.
DECLARE @v TABLE (searchString VARCHAR(100))
--Sample Inputs
INSERT INTO @v
SELECT *
FROM (
    VALUES ('smith')
        ,('1234')
        ,('london')
        ,('12/01/2020')
    ) t(v)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp
--Create a temporary table to loop the serach inputs
SELECT *
    ,0 AS IsProcessed
INTO #Temp
FROM @v

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(max) = 'SELECT * FROM customersview WHERE 1 = 1 '
DECLARE @searchString VARCHAR(100)
--Loop through each search input
WHILE (
        SELECT Count(*)
        FROM #Temp
        ) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @searchString = searchString
    FROM #Temp

    SELECT @searchString


    --Check if input is int/bigint type
    IF (ISNUMERIC(@searchString) = 1)
    BEGIN


        SET @query = @query + 'AND ' + @searchString + ' IN (' + Stuff((
                    SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Quotename(COLUMN_NAME)
                    FROM (
                        SELECT COLUMN_NAME
                            ,DATA_TYPE
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS v
                        JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c ON c.TABLE_SCHEMA = v.TABLE_SCHEMA
                            AND c.TABLE_NAME = v.TABLE_NAME
                        WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'customersview'
                            AND DATA_TYPE IN ('int', 'bigint')
                        ) t
                    FOR XML path('')
                        ,type
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') + ')'
    END
    --Check if input is date type
    ELSE IF (ISDATE(@searchString) = 1)
    BEGIN

        SET @query = @query + ' AND ''' + @searchString + ''' IN (' + Stuff((
                    SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Quotename(COLUMN_NAME)
                    FROM (
                        SELECT COLUMN_NAME
                            ,DATA_TYPE
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS v
                        JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c ON c.TABLE_SCHEMA = v.TABLE_SCHEMA
                            AND c.TABLE_NAME = v.TABLE_NAME
                        WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'customersview'
                            AND DATA_TYPE IN ('date', 'datetime')
                        ) t
                    FOR XML path('')
                        ,type
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') + ')'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    --Check if input is VARCHAR/NVARCHAR type
        SET @query = @query + ' AND ''' + @searchString + ''' IN (' + Stuff((
                    SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Quotename(COLUMN_NAME)
                    FROM (
                        SELECT COLUMN_NAME
                            ,DATA_TYPE
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS v
                        JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c ON c.TABLE_SCHEMA = v.TABLE_SCHEMA
                            AND c.TABLE_NAME = v.TABLE_NAME
                        WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'customersview'
                            AND DATA_TYPE IN ('VARCHAR', 'NVARCHAR')
                        ) t
                    FOR XML path('')
                        ,type
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') + ')'
    END

    DELETE #Temp
    WHERE searchString = @searchString
END

SELECT @query
--Execute the query
--EXEC(@Query)
```

Comment: This solution does the trick! I didn't think of XML to get the view's column.